# Integrating Virtualenv with two GitHub repositories

Tags: git, virtualenv

My problem is probably not the most complex, but since it uses complex and fundamental actions related to invisible files (git and virtualenv) it seems crucial to get right.

As far as I can tell, Virtualenv simply changes some path variables so the "frozen" branch is the one seen.  So, if you have two branches in your project (let's say front-end and back-end), is best practice to create a top-level directory called 'venv' in which you create the virtual environment, then you do two giti inits ('git init frontend' and 'git init backend') in subdirectories.This leaves us with a directory structure than looks like:

```
project (venv)
    +
front-end (Git repository1) 
    +--other_dirs
    +
back-end (Git repository2)
    +--other_dirs
```

Now each (independent) branch takes care of itself...but any common files aren't part of Git.

What is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 0):

Through experimentation, it looks like the strategy I laid out is the best/most functional.

Basically, you set up a top level directory which we can call "venv".  Then you create a virtual env while in that directory.  If you do, you'll see all the hidden files that implement virtualenv.  In particular, look at the 'secret' files (by doing "ls .*") So far, so good.

Now from there create two subdirectories, we'll call foo and bar.  move to the first and do a "git init" followed by a cloning of the repository for branch 1. (Don't forget to do a "git --add" followed by a "git commit" so that all of the Git files for subdirectory "foo" get stuck in that subdirectory.)

Now, change to the other branch ("cd ../bar") and do the same thing (i.e., "git init" followed by a clone, add and commit).  This should make bar and all its subdirectories be governed by its own Git repository.

What is a little confusing is that, in order to activate the virtual environment from being in the root of either sub-directory, you need to do a "source ../bin/activate".  In other words, the /bin directory under /venv is a peer of both directories which "hold" all of the magic Git files (again, try "ls .*" to make them appear).

But the virtual environment itself seems not to need to be part of anything Git knows about.

Still happy to hear other opinions, but this is amazingly little explained given how frequently one has a project with (say) a front-end and a back-end.